# Eclipse Git keyword expansion

Tags: eclipse, git, revision, egit, keyword-expansion

I need to to update my source code revision keywords (@version, @date, etc) every time I am checking out the source to the git-hub server.

As you might know:

> The main problem with this in Git is that you can’t modify a file with
>   information about the commit after you’ve committed, because Git
>   checksums the file first.

Basically what I want to achieve is that my source code should look like below:

```
 * Git revision information:
 * 
 * @version $Revision: 1e7f611039399b32e9000ec454609a0641dde368 $
 * @author  $Author: Eugen Mihailescu <eugenmihailescux@gmail.com> $
 * @date    $Date:   Thu May 3 01:17:45 2012 +0200 $
 * 
 * $Id:  | Thu May 3 01:17:45 2012 +0200 | Eugen Mihailescu  $
```

[Here](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) and [here](https://github.com/turon/git-rcs-keywords) you can find a full description of how you can achieve this in Git.

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing
>   substitutions in files on commit/checkout. These are the “clean” and
>   “smudge” filters. In the .gitattributes file, you can set a filter for
>   particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just
>   before they’re checked out (“smudge”, see Figure 7-2) and just before
>   they’re committed.

So I know how to do it with git command. I've tested, it just works!
My real issue is that I would like to achieve same thing by using Eclipse IDE.
In Eclipse I have Eclipse Git, which is an Eclipse Team provider based on JGit, a pure Java implementation of the Git version control system.

In Eclipse EGit there is no such command "git checkout" but one could accomplish that by a hard reset (right-click your project then choose Team -> Reset -> Hard). Unfortunately this will not run your clean/smudge filters, in fact you will get the plain copy of your sources from the git hub without no keyword expansion.

I hope that I have described in detail the whole story because now I will ask:

- is this possible in Eclipse using the EGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [commit (August 2010)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit?id=e2e38792b5403da38d5e3ab0e15b626e051107f2) commented

#### Perform automatic CRLF to LF conversion during WorkingTreeIterator

> **`WorkingTreeIterator`** now optionally performs CRLF to LF conversion for text files.
>   A basic framework is left in place to support enabling (or disabling) this feature based on `gitattributes`, and also to support the more generic smudge/clean filter system.
>   As there is no `gitattribute` support yet in JGit this is left unimplemented, but the `mightNeedCleaning()`, `isBinary()` and `filterClean()` methods will provide reasonable places to plug that into in the future.

I don't think `gitattribute` is fully supported in the [latest JGit releases](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/New_and_Noteworthy), and the [latest revision of `WorkingTreeIterator`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/WorkingTreeIterator.java#n404) has still an empty `filterClean()` function.

So using JGit alone might not be enough to trigger your "filter content" driver.

Comment: So there is no way of doing that via Eclipse? I mean, you don't have any clue of doing that, right?

Comment: @EugenMihailescu no way that I know of, except by implementing the `gitattribute` support in JGit itself, extending the class/functions I mention. My point was to make sure that even in the latest implementation of JGit, that particular feature wasn't yet there.

Comment: thank you; your answer was very clear from the beginning, my comment was intended (perhaps) to be rather rhetorical, though.